# How to create an automated column in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

IDE: Visual Studio, C# .net 4.0, Winforms application

Is there any way in SQL Server to implement a column in a table which can set itself automatically to 0 when it has not received any ACK (acknowledgement) signal from the application side?

The requirement is I want to keep a column which can keep track that Is application is open or it has been closed?

One way to implement is using the `OnClose()` event, i.e. on `Close()` I can change it's value to 0. but the problem is suppose application got hanged for some reason or Power is gone than the value in database will not be updated to zero.

So I want to create an automated column which can track this situation and make itself zero when the application is not sending any request or idle means closed.

please suggest how to handle this.

Comment: No, that's not possible - the column in SQL Server cannot listen and respond to events in your Winforms application. You'll have to handle this yourself, in your Winforms code, and just update the SQL Server column as needed

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. The only thing you can do is to save `GETDATE()` in a column in a table as the last activity time of the application and invoke the stored procedure from a high-priority thread every 10 seconds for example.

When you want to know if the application is alive or not, just check this value, if more than 10 seconds is passed since then, you app is gone.

UPDATE:
A more precise but complex approach would be to listen on a socket inside your application and then whenever you want to know if the application is alive, send a request from your sql script to `PING` the application. You should use CLR programming for this approach, but I think the first one will be practically enough.

Answer (score 0):

Considering it will be a multiple instance scenario where multiple instances of the application can point to same database. You can try the following:

1. Create a separate table to maintain sessions. This table would contain three columns 1)Machine name or IP 2) Session Id (GUID) and 3) TimeStamp.
2. Whenever application starts create a new session id and make an entry into this table it means new session is started.
3. Keep on updating timestamp on every request based on session id.
4. Have a timeout configured somewhere in web.config or database which will come in handy later.
5. Now when application is exiting gracefully then delete the row from the table.
6. Now if application crashes the row won't be delete so next time when application starts you can check if the row already exists. Use machine name or IP to query to the table.
7. Use the timeout setting configured in (3) above to determine since how long the application is idle.